# Test correct installation of sqlite3 after installation with Rails installer

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite

I used rails installer to install everything on my computer.I am trying to test if the database installed correctly with this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sqlite3'
puts "sqlite is working" if defined?( SQlite3::Database )
```

I am expecting it to print "sqlite is working" to the screen, but it is not doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sqlite3'

puts SQLite3::SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER
# >> 3006012
```

that is a bit more useful.

Or, you could spell the module's name correctly:

```
puts SQLite3::Database.class
# >> Class
```